# Can I use QueryDSL to "update" the mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, querydsl

I want to update the mongo collection based on some criteria. Can I do that with querydsl ?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html) mentions update queries for relational databases with [JPA](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration), but not for [MongoDB](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s07.html). For the latter, you'll have to first search the documents matching your criteria, then update them with separate command.